# Can anyone see transactions from a contract?

Tags: transactions, ether, contract-design

Can anyone see all outgoing Ether transactions from a contract?

If no, is it possible somehow to make the transactions visible? (maybe, using events?)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, everything is public, transparent. You can use an explorer like https://etherscan.io/. The transactions made by the contract are under the "Internal transactions" tab on etherscan, here's an [example](https://etherscan.io/address/0xde0b295669a9fd93d5f28d9ec85e40f4cb697bae).